# Current flow in PWM brushed DC motor drive

Tags: pwm, dc-motor, transient-suppression, spike

I am driving a brushed DC motor ([Cytron gear motor](https://www.robotshop.com/uk/12v-58rpm-60-1-gear-motor-encoder.html)) using a gate driver ([SN754410](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn754410.pdf)) to do PWM motor speed control.

[image: Buffered Motor Drive with SN754410]

## My expectation

I expected a triangular current wave, ramp up when PWM on, ramp down when PWM off. Like this (with sine speed modulation):

[image: Delta PWM from Wikimedia]

## My observations

However, instead I observed the following:

- Measured across 1 ohm resistor
- 80% PWM duty cycle
- Motor under load.
- Frequencies: 24-500 kHz
- PWM in purple, current in red (1V => 1A)

### 24 kHz

[image: 24kHz PWM, Loaded Brushed DC Motor]

### 200 kHz

[image: 200kHz PWM, Loaded Brushed DC Motor]

### 500 kHz

[image: 500kHz PWM, Loaded Brushed DC Motor]

## Questions

1. Why are there such big current spikes?
2. Should I expect this, and will it reduce the chip lifespan?
3. What should I do to suppress it? (I have put decoupling capacitors in, like the reference circuit. It made no significant difference.)

Comment: Triangles you expect will happen only when the time constant (L/R) is much higher than the switching period. The straight line is actually *beginning of the exponential*.

Comment: I think the negative spikes you are seeing is the inductive recirculation current. How did you connect the driver? as an half bridge or only as chopper?

Comment: The driver is attached as in the circuit diagram at the start. As a half H Bridge driver

Comment: Holy moly you are switching that thing fast! How come?

Comment: It seems like you drive a capacitor rather than a motor, else I don't understand those spikes and the current going backward.

Comment: Do you by any chance have a small decoupling capacitor in parallel with the motor? That would explain why there's extra current when you first turn on voltage, as well as why it takes the motor winding a while to start forcing current through the circuit when you turn off voltage.

Comment: @winny I was just experimenting with switching it fast out of curiosity! It's normally being switched at 24kHz so as to be inaudible.

Comment: @Luke no, there is no decoupling capacitor

Comment: That’s still really high. How big or small of a motor are we talking about?

Comment: @winny please see the link at the start of the question! Big or small is relative, but I would say big.

Comment: If you calculate the low pass filtering from the moment of inertia from the rotor, you can go down to hundreds if not tens of Hz without issue.

Comment: I did try lower frequencies but the noise was uncomfortable! I'm happy with operating at 24kHz.